# ¿Cómo muestro una columna cuyo nombre es una variable de php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Este es mi código php, lo que estoy intentando hacer es unos "anchor" que son generados a través de una base de datos MySQL y que son DISTINCT, para evitar que se repitan muestren en unos *badges* la cantidad de veces que ellos se repiten en la base de datos.

```
<h3>Clientes actuales</h3>
<div class="list-group">
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT cliente FROM empleadocass";
  $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
  while($mostra=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
    <?php $test = $mostrar['cliente']; ?>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><?php echo $test ?>
    <span class="badge">
    <?php
      $sq = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT $test) FROM empleadocass";
      $resul = mysqli_query($conexion, $sq);
      while($mostra = mysql_fetch_array($resul)) {
    ?>
    <?php echo $mostra['COUNT(DISTINCT $test)'] ?>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
    </span>
    </a>
<?php
  }
?>
</div>
```

Por ejemplo:

```
Angel Company (3)
Geo Company (4)
```

Comment: Por favor agrega tu código en vez de una imagen para ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 2):

Debes asignarle un alias a dicha columna en tu código SQL y luego usas ese alias para obtener el valor.

```
$sq = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT $test) AS cantidad FROM empleadoscass";

...

<?php echo $mostra['cantidad'] ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya tienes una respuesta que es válida, yo te voy a poner otra un poco diferente y que mejora un poco la eficiencia de tu programa:

```
<h3>Clientes actuales</h3>
<div class="list-group">
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT cliente, COUNT(*) AS cantidad FROM empleadocass GROUP BY cliente";
  $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
  while($mostra=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><?php echo $mostrar['cliente']; ?>
    <span class="badge">
    <?php echo $mostrar['cantidad']; ?>
    </span>
    </a>
<?php
  }
?>
</div>
```

La idea es que no necesitas hacer dos consultas, sino que lo puedes hacer todo en una sola usando `GROUP BY` (lo cual servirá varias funciones: agrupar los clientes de manera que no habrá duplicados y realizar el recuento) y ahorrarte peticiones a la base de datos y consultas.